# MVC3 ValidationAttribute validationContext.memberName is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I find half solutions everywhere but I cannot get a real answer for this.

I have created a validation attribute inheriting from ValidationAttribute and IClientValidatable.

Everything seems to work fine, and if I put a validation summary on the page the error displays.

however I cannot get the error displaying beside the textbox relating to the property.

I think this is because I need to add the property name to the validation result.

HOWEVER this is where it fails, because I cannot get the member name from the validationContext.

is there a way to enable this to happen? Or am I missing something?

```
public class AdmissionDayCaseAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private String DayCaseID;
    private String AdmissionDateID;
    private String DischargeDateID;

    public AdmissionDayCaseAttribute(String DayCaseID, String AdmissionDateID, String DischargeDateID)
    {
        this.DayCaseID = DayCaseID;
        this.AdmissionDateID = AdmissionDateID;
        this.DischargeDateID = DischargeDateID;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        object AdmissionDate = GetPropertyValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, AdmissionDateID);
        object DischargeDate = GetPropertyValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, DischargeDateID);
        object AdmissionType = validationContext.MemberName == null ? null : GetPropertyValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, validationContext.MemberName);
        if (AdmissionDate != null && DischargeDate != null && AdmissionType != null)
        {
            if (AdmissionDate.Equals(DischargeDate) && DayCaseID.Equals(AdmissionType.ToString()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new List<String>() { validationContext.MemberName });
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    private object GetPropertyValue(object instance,String propertyName)
    {
        Type itype = instance.GetType();
        return itype.GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(instance,null);
    }
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule vr = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "admissiondaycase"
        };
        vr.ValidationParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("admissiondateid", AdmissionDateID));
        vr.ValidationParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("dischargedateid", DischargeDateID));
        vr.ValidationParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("daycaseid", DayCaseID));
        yield return vr;
    }
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**

the view looks like this -

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AdmissionTypeID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.CustomDropDownListFor(a => a.AdmissionTypeID, Lookup.AdmissionTypes,Default.Constant.DROPDOWN)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.AdmissionTypeID)
    </td>
</tr>
```

There no javascript or anything interacting with this, its pretty basic however some extra details -
this view code is in a view template, which is used IN a partial view

Comment: Can you post your view as well? Have you included @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyName) besides your text boxes?

Comment: Have added the view, it definitely has the validtionmessagefor in the view - however server side the memberName doesn't show up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First check that the `AdmissionDayCaseAttribute` is correctly definied on the property in your model.

Then instead of returning `validationContext.MemberName` return `validationContext.DisplayName`. If you modified the member name through the `DsiplayAttribute` the you could do something like this :

```
  var memberName = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
    .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
    .Any(a => a.Name == validationContext.DisplayName))
    .Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault(); 

    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new List<String>() { memberName  });
```

Comment: I can understand why I would use the IValidatableObject, however I want it to valid a particular property, not the model itself.
The above although useful, doesn't fix my delima of not getting the memberName from the validationContext

Comment: Does the validationContext.DisplayName is empty ?

Comment: No the displayname is not empty, however it is not the same as the property name either (because i have declared a display attribute on the property as well)

Comment: This does work, however as unlikely as it is, if there are two properties with the same display name it won't - just thought i'd share it, thanks :)